# Publishing to file share in SDL web 8

Tags: publishing, web8, deployer

I have configured in deployer `cd_storage_conf.xml` for the deployer to deploy in file share on the basis of each publication. which means each publication content will go to its location mentioned in the storage.

```
<Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Type="filesystem" Id="FileShare" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false" Root Path="\\418604-fs1\tridion-static-nonprod\publication 1\" />
<Publication Id="118" cached="false" defaultStorageId="FileShare"> </Publication>
```

The issue I am facing here is that, it deploys lot of items which I don't need to.
E.g. when I publish a page, it deploys .html,.txt and meta information.

I just need to deploy .pdf, .xml and images.

I would like to know what all changes I need to do in `cd_storage_conf.xml` files.

Appreciate your help!

Regards,
Srikant

Answer (score 6):

You can add configuration in the cd_storage_conf on the deployer to deploy  files with a given extension at any given location.

To Configure which files you want to deploy to the file system, specify the item type mapping under the "ItemTypes" element like:

```
<Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".pdf" storageId="defaultFile"/>
```

After this configuration, all the .pdf files will be deployed to the given location. You can similarly configure any other filetype.

Comment: Thanks Vipin,I am able to publish to file share. but when I change my config to allow publishing to go to particular path for that publication, lot of items are getting published. In order to fix it we will have to add defaultStorageId="defaultdb" in publication node. you can see earlier I put defaultStorageId="FileShare".

Comment: You have to add item types to target what goes to file system like pdf while rest goes to db. If you change everything to defaultdb then nothing will go to file share while what I understood from the question was you selectively want to send pdf to file share rest everything to db. ItemTypes solve this use case where you want to change default deploy location for certain file types

Answer (score 2):

Since you are giving the defaultStorageId as file share that's why  .html,.txt and meta information is getting published to file system, if you want only specific items mentioned in your ItemTypes should be published to file system means you should give defaultStorageId of publication node database storage id, so that meta data and other items will be published to database and ItemTypes which are configured with storageId will go to the file system you mentioned.